# Unsupported operand types python3

Tags: python-3.x

So I keep getting the above error message, and I don't understand why. This is what I have so far:

```
#request user input for property value
def getPropertyValue():
  value = 0

  value = float(input('Please enter value of desired property: '))
  #eliminate negative answers
  if value < 0:
    print('Invalid property value, please re-enter a positive value. ')
    getPropertyValue()

  #return valid answers
  else: 
    return value
#calculate assessed value 
def calc_assessed_value(value):
  a_value = value * 0.60
  return a_value
#calculate property tax, 72 cents of each 100 dollars
def calc_property_tax(a_value):
  p_tax = a_value / 100 * 0.72
  p_tax = round(p_tax, 2) 
  return p_tax
#display results with meaningful text
def print_message(value, a_value , p_tax):
  print('Property Value: $' , value)
  print('Assessed Property Value: $' , a_value)
  print('Property Tax: $' , p_tax)
#run functions in order
value = getPropertyValue()

a_value = calc_assessed_value(value)

p_tax = calc_property_tax(a_value)

print_message(value , a_value , p_tax)
```

And when I run it with a positive number out of the gate, it works. If I continuously run negative numbers it cuts it off as intended, and loops them until they enter a non-negative number. However, when you enter a positive number after that, it give the error message. I've been at this a while and it's not making sense to me. I thought maybe entering a negative number was affecting what type of number it was trying to use, so I tried zeroing the total before inputting (which is why there is a value = 0), but it still doesn't allow it through.

Comment: provide complete error stack

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do `getPropertyValue` recursive, you should return function instead of executing it only. 
Add return statement here:

```
    #eliminate negative answers
    if value < 0:
        print('Invalid property value, please re-enter a positive value. ')
        return getPropertyValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getPropertyValue` function, when the user enters a negative number, you recursively call `getPropertyValue()` again and yet you aren't returning its return value, so it returns `None` by default, causing the `calc_assessed_value` to do calculation with a `None` value later.

Simply change:

```
getPropertyValue()
```

to:

```
return getPropertyValue()
```

Comment: I get what you’re saying, and I thank you for the help, but I’m curious: shouldn’t me re-zeroing the value before the input change the none to zero?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to zero `value`. When the user enters a negative number, you call `getPropertyValue()` and return its value, and `getPropertyValue()` in turn asks the user for input and return the new `value` if it's a valid one. That's all.